# Gradle parent and sub-projects as siblings

Tags: gradle

In a gradle multi-module project, can the parent and sub-projects be siblings?

```
-parent
--build.gradle
--settings.gradle
-sub-project-1
--build.gradle
-sub-directory
--sub-module-2-1
---build.gradle
--sub-module-2-2
---build.gradle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to configure it this way, by declaring subprojects within `settings.gradle` as `includeFlat` instead of simple `include`. You can read about it [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#includeFlat%28java.lang.String[]%29)

But in that case, you have to run Gradle from the directory. where `settings.gradle` file is located, otherwise it won't find any subprojects.

Comment: includeFlat seems to be working, but the problem is if a child project depends on another child that's in a sub-directory - adding compile project ("../dir1/mod1") is not working.